# Нужно ли ставить двоеточие перед цитатой?

Tags: грамотная-речь, двоеточие

Нужно ли здесь двоеточие перед цитатой?

Задавая Алексею вопрос(**:**) "Что ты тут делаешь?", Веселов надеялся на то, что Алексей ему внятно ответит.

Часто задавая вопрос(**:**) "Куда ты собрался", можно нарваться на ответ(:) "Не твоё собачье дело!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно записать так:

(1) *Задавая Алексею вопрос: **"Что ты тут делаешь?"**, Веселов надеялся на то, что Алексей ему внятно ответит.*

(2) *Часто задавая вопрос **"Куда ты собрался?"**, можно нарваться на ответ: **"Не твоё собачье дело!"***

**Пояснение**

Цитаты могут оформляться в виде **прямой** или косвенной речи, с помощью вводных слов, обозначающих автора, а также **встраиваться** в авторскую речь. В некоторых случаях выбор варианта оформления является **авторским**, но чаще он определяется содержанием, структурой и **интонацией** предложения, а также необходимостью отделить прямую речь от авторских слов.

Следует учесть, что наибольшую **выделительную** способность имеет прямая речь в обычном оформлении.

(1) Обычная прямая речь: **конкретное** высказывание.

(2) Неоднократно **повторяемое** действие, упрощенное оформление вопроса без двоеточия (нет паузы). А ответ можно оформить с использованием **двоеточия**, обозначив паузу.

Comment: А в первом варианте не должно быть тире вместо запятой после прямой речи? Там же вопросительный знак завершает прямую речь.

Comment: Я подумала об этом. Но это ведь цитата, а не прямая речь в обычном смысле, когда автор приводит реальную речь действующих лиц.

Comment: "Цитаты заключаются в кавычки. Если цитата оформляется как прямая речь, т. е. сопровождается словами автора, приводящего ее, то применяются соответствующие правила пунктуации (ссылки на предыдущие параграфы оформления прямой речи)". Из Розенталя, собственно. Или это какой-то другой случай?

Comment: Вы можете привести пример применения правила Розенталя к цитированию. когда ставится тире,а не запятая из-за вопросительного знака? Если найдете, то я не против тире. Но мне оно кажется в данном случае неуместным при цитировании. Но я дополнительно использую интонационный контроль,  отсюда и получился "особый случай". В реальной прямой речи увеличенная пауза делается, она и обозначается тире. Удивительно, но интонационный анализ можно применить даже к прямой речи.

Comment: Не хочу долго искать, если такой пример подойдёт, то вот: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091327.html Пункт 8. Цитаты, подпункт 8.8.3 _Когда литсотрудник подписывал ответ на вопрос читателя: «Сохраняются ли витамины в фруктовых соках?» — он, по-видимому, не был озабочен…_ В подпункте 8.8.2. есть слова о запятой после цитаты, если она в конце деепричастного оборота, но нет упоминаний случая вопросительного знака в конце цитаты. Не понимаю, имеются там в виду любые знаки в конце цитат или нет. В общем, интересны мне были причины постановки запятой у вас, вот и всё.

Comment: Спасибо, материал хороший. Если интересно, прокомментирую ваши примеры.  К сожалению, деепричастного оборота нет, а он здесь интересен в первую очередь. Почему? Дело в том, что тире с СПП с придаточным времени и так допускается правилами,  а здесь тем более не помешает.  А вот ставить тире после деепричастного оборота?  И графика нехороша, и произошению не соответствует.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо за пояснения! Буду знать, что и такое возможно тоже.